# How to loop through a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql, select

I have this select statement

```
declare @t table (Percentage float)
DECLARE @acc INT 
SET @acc = 1
DECLARE @max INT 
select @max = max(HireID) from NewHire
WHILE (@acc <= @max)
    BEGIN
        IF (@acc in (select HireID from NewHire))
            BEGIN try
                insert into @t  
                select
                    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
                    CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) as FLOAT)
            END try
            begin catch
                insert into @t 
                select 0.0
            end catch
        set @acc = @acc + 1
    END
select * from @t
```

In this code, I am looping through all the NewHire records by its id, from 1 to the highest one. I realized this is not what I want to do anymore. Now basically I have this stored procedure called `sp_selectNewHire2SQL` which gets the NewHire table in a specific way. I want to call it, and aquire its returning recordset, and then loop through that from top to bottom.

Note: That doing a loop from id 1 to highest wont work anymore, because the order of the id's could be mixed up.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered a single SELECT? There is no need for a loop. Also, adding a stored procedure does not add value. DRY is not always good for SQL Code

Comment: How can you do this with a single select statement? Also I want to call a stored procedure because my asp classic code, calls that stored procedure, and I dont want to have same code in different places.

Comment: "I dont want to have same code in different places." you shouldn't. Each code does something different so you have not repeated... ANd "I realized this is not what I want to do anymore" = what is now your processing needed?

Comment: Well, I am trying to do a select statement, and then loop through all it's rows from top to bottom.

Comment: Please please please stop using SP_ for your stored procedure names. How is it not common knowledge at this point that this is a BAD practice?

Comment: OP please read http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25348/still-wrong-to-start-the-name-of-a-user-stored-procedure-with-sp

Comment: Also please read http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Answer (score 3):

As a single SELECT, something like this

```
select
    NH.HireID,
    ISNULL(1E0 *
          COUNT(CASE WHEN HireResponse IN (0,1) THEN HR.HireID END) / 
          NULLIF(COUNT(HR.HireID), 0)
       , 0) AS percentage
from
    NewHire NH
    LEFT JOIN
    Hire_Response HR ON NH.HireID = HR.HireID
group by
    NH.HireID
```

Comment: There is a syntax error near AS.